# classical solution of nondegenerate HJB equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Let $b\in C(\mathbb R)$ and $L \in C_b^2(\mathbb R)$. Consider an equation
$$v_t (x, t) + \inf_{a\in A} \{b(a) v_x(x, t) + a^2 \} + v_{xx}(x, t) + L(x) = 0, \hbox{ on } \mathbb R \times (0, 1)$$
with terminal condition
$$v(x, 1) = 0.$$
According to Theorem VI.4.2 of [This Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Bjz2iWmLyQC&lpg=PA162&vq=are%20taken%20for%20granted&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q&f=false), there exists unique solution $v\in C_b^{2,1}$ if $A$ is compact. Does the same result still hold if $A$ is $\mathbb R$?